# Make an ActionBar Button appear from press of ListView's onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-actionbar

I currently have a fragment which contains a listView, and I would like a button to become visible when a user selects an item from the listView. I have tried the following code:

```
MenuItem infoButton = menu.findItem(R.id.moreInfoButton);
infoButton.setVisible(true);
```

All I get on a list item click is some other basic functionality that I have to display more information about the item selected, but only this functionality doesn't work. The log shows this when I press the list item with the above code in a try-catch block:

```
11-17 12:50:39.211  14126-14126/myPackage W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 12:50:39.216  14126-14126/myPackage W/System.err﹕ at myPackage.fragmentName$3.onItemClick(fragmentName.java:417)
```

Any ideas what I could be doing? Maybe declaring a Menu item and findViewByID to the menu layout file? Or is that the incorrect way of going about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean field on your fragment/activity that indicates if you're showing the button or not. Change it's value on your `onItemClick` and after you change it call `Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu`. This will call `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. In that method check for your field and show/hide the button you want on your action bar.

Comment: Just to clarify your response, where should I declare the button that is in the action bar? And would I then change its visibility by something like: buttonName.setVisible(booleanValue)? I ask because I set visibility to false in onCreateView (which causes a crash) and then try to set it to true in the onClick.

Comment: You declare the button on the menu xml. Set it to invisible first. And change its visibility on `onPreparateOptionsMenu`

Comment: Okay I declared the button and set visibility to false. Then in Java I declare "private MenuItem myButton;" and "myButton= menu.findItem(R.id.actionBarButton);" in onCreateView. I then have "myButton.setVisible(true);" in onPrepareOptionsMenu - or should it be in onClick?. And when I try to put in Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu, the second part says it cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: Please read my answer again. You dont seem to understand what a flag is.